# Pyqt5 app doesn't print the selected values from HTML Combobox table

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt5, qcombobox

The following code is a PYQT5 app that display a HTML Qombobox table. The HTMLBridge(QObject) class printed the selected values from the qombobox table into lists. When I added the HTMLBridge(QObject) to Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow) class, the code does not update and print the lists of selected values from combobox table. How to overcome this issue?

The code is:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebChannel import QWebChannel
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTabWidget, QScrollArea, QComboBox
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets

class HTMLBridge(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.selected_values = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
        
    @pyqtSlot(str, int, int)
    def setSelectedValue(self, value, row, col):
        self.selected_values[row][col] = value
        self.printSelectedValues()
        
    def printSelectedValues(self):
        print("Selected values:")
        for row in self.selected_values:
            print(row)

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.initWindow()

    def initWindow(self):
        self.setFixedSize(1800, 1200)
        self.buttonUI()

    def buttonUI(self):
        self.button3 = QPushButton('button', self)
        self.button3.move(50, 150)
        self.button3.setFixedSize(200, 30)
        self.button3.clicked.connect(self.open_new_window1)

        self.W = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(self)
        self.W.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(275, 250, 0, 0))
        self.W.setFixedSize(0,0)

    def open_new_window1(self):
        self.SW1 = HTMLBridge()
        self.W.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(275, 0, 0, 0))
        self.W.setFixedSize(1300,500)
        bridge = HTMLBridge()
        channel = QWebChannel()
        channel.registerObject("bridge", bridge)
        self.W.page().setWebChannel(channel)
        self.W.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile("/index.html"))
        self.W.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
screen = Window()
screen.show()
app.exec_()
```

The index.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <body>
            <style>
                body {
                    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                    background-color: #0d026b;
                }

                h1 {
                    color: #333;
                }

                table {
                    border-collapse: collapse;
                    width: 50%;
                    background-color: #fff;
                    margin-bottom: 20px;
                }

                th, td {
                    padding: 10px;
                    text-align: left;
                    border-bottom: 2px solid #ec6efa;
                }

                th {
                    background-color: #f2f2f2;
                }
            </style>

            <h2 style="color:#fffb00">Title</h2>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Site</th> <th>C1</th> <th>C2</th> <th>C3</th>
                </tr> 
        <tr> <th>Row-1</th>
            <td>
                <select id="myComboBox00" onchange="sendSelectedValue(0, 0)">
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="0.33">0.33</option>
                    <option value="0.66">0.66</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="myComboBox01" onchange="sendSelectedValue(0, 1)">
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="0.33">0.33</option>
                    <option value="0.66">0.66</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="myComboBox02" onchange="sendSelectedValue(0, 2)">
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="0.33">0.33</option>
                    <option value="0.66">0.66</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> <th>Row-2</th>
            <td>
                <select id="myComboBox10" onchange="sendSelectedValue(1, 0)">
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="0.33">0.33</option>
                    <option value="0.66">0.66</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="myComboBox11" onchange="sendSelectedValue(1, 1)">
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="0.33">0.33</option>
                    <option value="0.66">0.66</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="myComboBox12" onchange="sendSelectedValue(1, 2)">
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="0.33">0.33</option>
                    <option value="0.66">0.66</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> <th>Row-3</th>
            <td>
                <select id="myComboBox20" onchange="sendSelectedValue(2, 0)">
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="0.33">0.33</option>
                    <option value="0.66">0.66</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="myComboBox21" onchange="sendSelectedValue(2, 1)">
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="0.33">0.33</option>
                    <option value="0.66">0.66</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="myComboBox22" onchange="sendSelectedValue(2, 2)">
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="0.33">0.33</option>
                    <option value="0.66">0.66</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> <th>Row-4</th>
            <td>
                <select id="myComboBox30" onchange="sendSelectedValue(3, 0)">
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="0.33">0.33</option>
                    <option value="0.66">0.66</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="myComboBox31" onchange="sendSelectedValue(3, 1)">
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="0.33">0.33</option>
                    <option value="0.66">0.66</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="myComboBox32" onchange="sendSelectedValue(3, 2)">
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="0.33">0.33</option>
                    <option value="0.66">0.66</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="qrc:///qtwebchannel/qwebchannel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var bridge;

        new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function(channel) {
            bridge = channel.objects.bridge;
        });

        function sendSelectedValue(row, col) {
            var comboBox = document.getElementById("myComboBox" + row + col);
            var selectedValue = comboBox.options[comboBox.selectedIndex].value;
            bridge.setSelectedValue(selectedValue, row, col);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Both `bridge` and `channel` will be immediately garbage-collected, since you did not keep a reference to them.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've used "self.bridge = None" and "self.channel = None" in Window and all goes well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It solved by using "self.bridge = None" and "self.channel = None" in Window() class.